# Modifying YouTube iframe API script to work with iframe embedding

Tags: javascript, timestamp, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-iframe-api

So, I have a working script ([see working code here](https://codepen.io/snicla/pen/jOOyVJx)) that displays a YouTube video and a list of links with timestamps.

When you click on a link with data-stamp="60" it starts playing video from 0:60. This is the functionality I need.

The problem is that the video gets loaded through JS into the `<div id="player">` with this code

```js
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    videoId: 'e9dZQelULDk',
    playerVars: {
      start: 0,
      rel: 0,
      showinfo: 0,
      autohide: 0
    },
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady
    }
  });
}
```

My goal is to load video using youtube's iframe like this

```
<iframe width="1280" height="720" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/e9dZQelULDk" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

And to keep using the part of the script that handles linking to a certain time in the video.

So, my question is, is it possible by just editing this existing script I'm currently using. I tried loading the video with iframe and deleting the part of the script that calls for the video by ID but the links just don't work anymore and that doesn't really surprise me since my knowledge of JS is minimal. Hope to get some help here! :)

Comment: The JS creates an iFrame and inserts it into your document. I am not sure I understand why that is not acceptable?

Comment: It's not unacceptable, it's inconvenient for the client to edit JS every time they need to use a video with the timestamps.

Comment: Is there's another way of making it easier for the client to insert a video instead of messing around with JS code. Maybe something like <div video-id="xyz123", and then using JS to insert that code into the script?